# Add elements to nested Map efficiently

Tags: f#

I have a nested Map like so:

```
Map<int, Map<int, int>>
```

And I want to be able to add an element to the nested Map as efficiently and neatly as possible.

My current solution is something like this:

```
let AddStuff (collection:Map<int, Map<int, int>>) firstID secondID value = 
    let newValue = collection.[firstID].Add(secondID, value)
    let newCollection = collection.Add(firstID, newValue)
    newCollection
```

This to me doesn't seem to be the `F#` way of doing things so was wondering on what is the best way to add to a nested Map?

**Edit**
Some expected input/output:

```
let aMap = map[(1, map[(1, 1)])]
let firstID = 1
let secondID = 2
let value = 2

let newMap = aMap firstID secondID value

// newMap = map[(1, map[(1, 1); (2, 2)])]
```

**Edit 2**

It seems that partialCollection had no effect on the output, so I've removed it from the function.

Comment: The problem would be easier to understand if you supply some test cases (input and expected output) as well.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Sorry, editing problems. I changed the 3rd line in the function to represent partialCollection

Comment: I see you just edited your question, as you've discovered that `Map.Add` in F# is essentially "add or replace". What you've got now looks to me like it's the right way to do it, so you've essentially answered your own question by editing it, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @rmunn Gotta love it when that happens :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be slightly more functional in style, you could replace those `.Add` method calls with calls to the `Map.add` function (a function on the `Map` module, not a method call on the individual `Map` objects). You might also want to move the `collection` argument for your `AddStuff` function to the last argument, so that it can be more easily used with the `|>` operator. Then it would look like:

```
let AddStuff firstID secondID value (collection:Map<int, Map<int, int>>) = 
    let newValue = collection.[firstID] |> Map.add secondID value
    collection |> Map.add firstID newValue
```

And you could use it like:

```
let newMap = aMap |> AddStuff firstID secondID value
```

Up to you to decide which style you like better, but I like the `|>` style better myself, as it lets me think in terms of "this data is getting piped through these operations".

**Edit:** That function might look a bit nicer with some whitespace:

```
let AddStuff firstID secondID value (collection:Map<int, Map<int, int>>) = 
    let newValue =
        collection.[firstID]
        |> Map.add secondID value
    collection |> Map.add firstID newValue
```

Comment: That is an even better improvement! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's one problem with the solutions you have so far. Asking for a key that's not in the map using the indexer throws - you can't add something that's not already in the top-level map that way. So a call like `AddStuff aNewMap 7 11 3` will break.

Here's a neat way of doing it - first define a generic update function:

```
/// Update a value for key if it exists,
/// otherwise return a new map with that value  
let update key f maybeColl = 
    match maybeColl with
    | Some coll ->
        let maybeElem = Map.tryFind key coll
        Map.add key (f maybeElem) coll
    | None ->
        Map.ofList [key, f None]
```

Then compose your function from updates:

```
/// Given a two-level map, adds a value to the nested map.
let add2 firstKey secondKey value coll =
    (Some coll)
    |> update firstKey (
        update secondKey (fun _ -> value))
```

Making `update` easily composable means that you can easily write an `add3` or a function that would map over a value in the nested map for  for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my full solution already checks to see if the key is in there within the function

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so as @rmunn said in the comment section, Map.Add is essentially "add or replace"

So my original function, which was:

```
let AddStuff (collection:Map<int, Map<int, int>>) firstID secondID value = 
    let newValue = collection.[firstID].Add(secondID, value)
    let partialCollection = collection.Remove(firstID)
    let newCollection = partialCollectioncollection.Add(firstID, newValue)
    newCollection
```

Now becomes:

```
let AddStuff (collection:Map<int, Map<int, int>>) firstID secondID value = 
    let newCollection = collection.Add(firstID, collection.[firstID].Add(secondID, value))
    newCollection
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for efficiency and neatness. A rather neat approach is to use Lenses to update properties of an immutable type.

```
module Lenses =
  // A Lens is a type that allows "focusing" on a property of a type
  //  A Lens consists of a get and set function

  // Inspired by: http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/01/haskell-for-mainstream-programmers_28.html

  //                          getter     setter
  type Lens<'T, 'V> = Lens of ('T -> 'V)*('V -> 'T -> 'T)

  let inline get  (Lens (g, _)) v     = g v
  let inline set  (Lens (_, s)) n v   = s n v

  // >-> chains two Lenses, allows focusing on property of a property of a type
  let ( >-> ) (f : Lens<'T, 'V>) (s : Lens<'V, 'U>) : Lens<'T, 'U> =
    Lens (get f >> get s, fun n v -> set f (set s n (get f v)) v)

  // fstL is a Lens that focuses on the first element in a pair
  let fstL<'T, 'U>  : Lens<'T*'U, 'T> = 
    Lens (fst, fun n v -> (n, snd v))
  // sndL is a Lens that focuses on the second element in a pair
  let sndL<'T, 'U>  : Lens<'T*'U, 'U> = 
    Lens (snd, fun n v -> (fst v, n))
  // mapzL is a Lens that focuses on an element in a map, z is the zero value if not present
  let mapzL k z     : Lens<Map<'K, 'V>, 'V> = 
    let get v = 
      match Map.tryFind k v with
      | Some e -> e
      | _ -> z
    let set = Map.add k
    Lens (get, set)
  // mapzL is a Lens that focuses on an element in a map
  let inline mapL k = mapzL k LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero

open Lenses

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  // Creates an empty map of a map
  let empty     : Map<string, Map<int, float>> = Map.empty

  // Uses Lenses to update the map
  //  Has to pass Map.empty to mapzL as Map doesn't have a Zero member
  let modified1 = empty     |> set (mapzL "A" Map.empty >-> mapL 2) 3.
  let modified2 = modified1 |> set (mapzL "B" Map.empty >-> mapL 3) 4.
  let modified3 = modified2 |> set (mapzL "B" Map.empty >-> mapL 4) 5.

  printfn "%A" empty
  printfn "%A" modified1
  printfn "%A" modified2
  printfn "%A" modified3

  0
```